# How to handle Static method call of ThirdParty class while junit testing using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am facing problem while testing method using Mockito.
please check testMethodToBeTested() method of JunitTestCaseClass, which has to handle static method call of thirdparty class.

```
class ClasssToBeTested{

    public String methodToBeTested() {
        String result = ThirdPartyUtilClass.methodToBeCall();
        return result;
    }
}

class ThirdPartyUtilClass{

    public static String methodToBeCall(){
        return "OK";
    }
}

// JunitTestCase which will test method "methodToBeTested()" of ClasssToBeTested class
class JunitTestCaseClass{

    @InjectMocks
    private ClasssToBeTested classsToBeTested;

    @Test
    public void testMethodToBeTested() {
        //How to handle ThirdPartyUtilClass.methodToBeCall(); statement in unit testing
        String result = classsToBeTested.methodToBeTested();
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

**Please help & Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer why it is not working:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ

**What are the limitations of Mockito**

> Mockito 2.x specific limitations

```
Requires Java 6+
Cannot mock static methods
Cannot mock constructors
Cannot mock equals(), hashCode().
```

Firstly, you should not mock those methods. Secondly, Mockito defines and depends upon a specific implementation of these methods. Redefining them might break Mockito.
    Mocking is only possible on VMs that are supported by Objenesis. Don't worry, most VMs should work just fine.
    Spying on real methods where real implementation references outer Class via OuterClass.this is impossible. Don't worry, this is extremely rare case.

If you really want to mock static methods then **PowerMock** is your solution.
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito